# how to do less than django queryset with column parameter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I want to count my stock as this sql code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM management_stock
WHERE stockCount < minStock
```

How to do that query in django queryset?
I got error in my this query:

```
Stock.objects.all().filter(stockCount__lt=minStock).count()
```

my table is like this:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bengkel = models.OneToOneField(Bengkel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stockCount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    minStock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I tried that code then my eror is : NameError: name 'minStock' is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [**`F`**-expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to reference a field, so:

```
from django.db.models import F

Stock.objects.filter(stockCount__lt=F('minStock')).count()
```